# How to cycle through variables without a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

After using R for the last little bit, I have distanced myself from using for loops for everything, but I still don't know how to cycle through names without using for loops. Whenever I am processing mulitple things, I will use for loops as a way to cover all my bases in one go. Here is a mock example of something I would do. Is there a simpler way to go about doing this?

```
names <- c("John_Doe","Jane_Doe")
employee <- vector(length = length(names))
for(i in 1:length(names)){
    filename <- paste0(names[i],".csv")
    employee[i] <- read.csv(filename,header = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: You could just do `names <- c("John_Doe","Jane_Doe") ; employee <- lapply(paste0(names, ".csv"), read.csv, header = FALSE)` I guess. You won't need to predefine `employee`this way. Also, `paste` is vectorized so no need to put it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's simpler, but you could try this:

```
dfs <- lapply(seq_along(names), function(i) read.csv(paste0(names[i], ".csv"), header = FALSE))
```

Instead of looping it's applying the same function to your index or 1 through the length of your names vector

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: sorry didn't see that - I think yours is simpler/better